# Why elements of HtmlElement equal to null

Tags: visual-studio-2008

The below code gives me a crash every time because elements3 is null so how to make the elements3 have some elements before I reach the loop

```
Dim elements3 As HtmlElement
    For Each elements3 In WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
        If elements3.GetAttribute("tabindex") = "1" Then
            elements3.SetAttribute("value", Text_TO_Pass_2)
        End If
    Next

    For Each webpageelemnt3 As HtmlElement In WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If webpageelemnt3.GetAttribute("name") = "sbutton" Then
            If webpageelemnt3.GetAttribute("tabindex") = "1" Then
                webpageelemnt3.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End If
    Next


    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    WebBrowser3.Navigate(TextBox3.Text)
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  What does the exception say and what line throws the exception?  "It crashes, how do I fix it?" isn't a problem description.

Comment: You haven't actually set elements3 to anything, you've told your compiler to allocate memory for it but you never actually initialize it...

Comment: [check this link, I'm sure you can modify this code to work for your means.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetElementsByTagName` seems to return `Nothing`, which is normal behavior if there are no elements found in the standard DOM model (it doesn't return an empty list). So before iterating through the result, check for nothing.

```
Dim elements3 As HtmlElement
elements3 = WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")

If Elements3 IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each elements3 In WebBrowser3.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
        If elements3.GetAttribute("tabindex") = "1" Then
            elements3.SetAttribute("value", Text_TO_Pass_2)
        End If
    Next
End if
```